# display DOM when it is ready

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple method to hide the bigger part of website, display loader.gif and nicely show the content with jquery until whole DOM is ready ? How can I code it ? Ofc I do not want use AJAX, just jquery.

Comment: I doubt there is a reliable method for doing this (assuming there is any). By the way: why not AJAX? It would be extremely simple to do this with AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

use `visibility:hidden / visible` on the part you don't want to show until dom is ready.
and once The DOM is ready ( `$('document').ready();`)  , make your content visible with animation or anyway you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using jQuery document.ready, which will only apply its functions/actions once the whole DOM is loaded.

You can do this by setting the body to be `visibility:hidden`, and then add a class with the document.ready function, which changes this to `visibility:visible`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/vvYVK/) - have a look how it works.

(Try changing the `"show"` to any other word if you want to test that it's working.)

I personally wouldn't suggest this though, on slow connections the website may just appear broken, or potentially flick on/off as the css is loaded, and then jQuery.

As mentioned in the comments if you need content loaded in a cleaner fashion AJAX is usually the way to go.